# Preciso criar uma sequencia de numeros iguais dentro de duas colunas no banco

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Olá galera sou novo com manipulação de códigos mysql, preciso de ajudar pra criar uma sequencia numérica nas colunas registro_inicial e registro_final, observação: os registros tem que ser iguais nas duas colunas!
Nota: Quero repetir as informações das demais colunas gerando a sequencia somente em registro_inicial e registro_final, ambas colunas como mesmo numero da sequencia
Desde já agradeço!

```
INSERT INTO tabela ('empresa','nome', 'telefone', 'registro_inicial', 'registro_final', 'id_venda', 'justificativa', 'data_inserido', 'protocolo') 
    VALUES (1, 'Joao', '99999-0000', '', '', 'Venda no crediario', '2020-11-04 15:43:09', NULL);
    WHERE registro_inicial > 000001
    AND registro_final <100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem a tua pergunta, mas olhando assim por cima tu pode fazer isso, é só substituir aqueles campos vazios e inserir os números que tu quer. E tirar esse where. Where é pra quando voce da um SELECT, ele não funciona no insert. Tem como voce inserir e dar um SELECT com WHERE pra conseguir campos registros específicos, mas ai é outra coisa...

[EDIT]
Após tua resposta, entendi que você quer fazer um update e não um insert, nesse caso seria.

```
UPDATE tabela SET registro_inicial='valor', registro_final='valor2' WHERE registro_inicial > 000001 AND registro_final <100000
```

Comment: Entao eu quero manter os registros das demais colunas e colocar uma sequencia numerica nas colunas registro_inicial e registro_final e atraves dessa sequencia gerar a quantidade de linhas conforme a sequencia setada, nao sei se fui claro.

Comment: Ai voce tem que fazer um update e não um insert.

UPDATE NOME_DA_TABELA SET campo1 = valor1, campo2 = valor2 WHERE campo1 = 'valor';

Comment: Entao mas no update vou duplicar as demais informações? gerando novos numeros na sequencia nas colunas registro_inicial e registro_final?
porque nao preciso só alterar, eu preciso gerar novas linhas repetindo todas informações das demais colunas e informações novas, somente nas colunas registro_inicial e registro_final.

Comment: no update as outras colunas vão ficar com mesmo valor. Tudo que tu passar depois do set é o que tu vai atualizar. No caso ali, registro inicial e registro final onde (where) o registro_inicial maior que 000001 e registro_final < 100000.

Então todos registros que atenderem esse requisito do where vão atualizar só os dois campos que tu botou no SET

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer aqui e aviso aqui se deu certo

Comment: Tu quer duplicar as outras informações? Tu quer inserir uma nova linha na tabela seria isso? Nesse caso não tem um jeito simples de fazer. Teria que usar um Linguagem de programação pra fazer essa regra.

Comment: Isso mesmo, quero duplicar as demais informações, inserindo novas linhas, seguindo a sequencia setada nas duas colunas registro_inicial > 000001 e registro_final < 100000

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116149/discussion-between-willian-ferrera-and-ricardo-jm-sistemas).